# Не дают голоса на мете

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Привет. В связи с тем, что я никогда раньше не писал на мету, а вот сейчас пришлось. У меня появился вопрос, к сообществу. Почему за "голоса за" на мете не дают репу?

Comment: например, чтобы не снимать ее, за голоса против